# Eclipse- projects created in a nested folder can't run

Tags: java, eclipse, nested

I Created a java project in eclipse in a nested folder on my desktop, but I kept getting the error :  Could not find or load main class.

I tried clean & rebuild, change run configurations and change JRE,but nothing helped.

I noticed that when I'm created the same project on the desktop it works,
someone knows why?
Thanks.

Comment: Is eclipse in a nested folder or the project itself? How do you start the project, via eclipse or via the console? Might be a problem with your paths.

Comment: The project itself.I started it via eclipse

Comment: Could you show us the run configurations?